# Why can intersection types contain conflicting types?

Tags: typescript

Given two interfaces with conflicting member types:

```
interface A { x: number }
interface B { x: string }
```

It is not possible to define an interface that extends both:

```
interface I extends A, B
// error TS2320: Interface 'I' cannot simultaneously extend types 'A' and 'B'.
// Named property 'x' of types 'A' and 'B' are not identical.
```

It *is* possible to define an intersection type that includes `A` and `B`:

```
let c = A & B
type C = A & B 
// no type errors
```

Although it is not possible to create an instance of this type:

```
let withNumber: C = { x: 10 }
error TS2322: Type '{ x: number; }' is not assignable to type 'A & B'.
Type '{ x: number; }' is not assignable to type 'B'.
Types of property 'x' are incompatible.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

let withString: C = { x: "foo" }
// The same type error, with `number` and `string` reversed
```

Is there a technical reason that intersection types do not report conflicts when they are defined?

Comment: It is possible to define that interface: `interface I extends A, B { x: number & string }` !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`type` operands [can be type parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3622#issuecomment-118417888); `interface... extends` operands must be concrete types.

That distinction makes `type` more flexible than `interface` (it's pretty much the motivation for `type`).

One consequence is that the `type` operator cannot know its complete set of member types ahead of time, so conflicts like this example cannot be detected.

[To quote Anders Hejlsberg](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4278#issuecomment-130240112),

> Now, the ability for the operands to be type parameters also deeply
>   affects the (possible) semantics of the operator. In particular, the
>   operator has to consistently work for any two operands with an unknown
>   set of members because it isn't possible to meaningfully report errors
>   during type instantiation (i.e. when real types are substituted for
>   type parameters). This what gives rise to the differences between &
>   and extends. Because the actual types are always known with extends we
>   can do more checking and forbid constructs that we deem wrong from a
>   classical OOP perspective. For example, we can error when properties
>   of the same name but different types conflict with extends, whereas we
>   merge (i.e. intersect) their types with &.

For more information see a [Github issue with a similar question](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4278) and the [pull request for intersection types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3622).

Comment: Great answer and +1 for quoting Anders. However this has changed, you can now extend/implement arbitrary type aliases, even when they include mapped types. This was added to support the mixin pattern. Please consider updating your answer. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#22-february-2017

Comment: @AluanHaddad as I understand it, the key point for this question is that you can use `type T<X, Y> = X & Y`, but not `interface I<X,Y> extends X, Y {  }`. Interfaces can extend more types in 2.2, but not type parameters.

Comment: Good point, it depends on how you read it. I did not interpret it as being about type parameters. This is now valid, but requires the intermediate intersection `type A = { x: number };
type B = { x: string };
type AB = A & B;
interface I extends AB { }
declare const i: I; i.x.toExponential(); i.x.trim();` anyway, this is a good answer in general.